# Undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass, for @topics

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to display a content on a page. I have:

**index.html.erb**

```
<if !user_signed_in? %>
  <%= link_to 'Download Topics', resumes_url, :class => 'btn btn-danger' %>
  <%= form_tag topics_path, :method => 'get' do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
  <% end %>

  <% @topics.each do |topic| %>
    <div class="topic">
      <h3><%= topic.title %></h3>
      <p><%= topic.id %></p>
      <p class="text-justify" ><%= topic.body %></p>
      <p><%= topic.date %></p>

      <%= image_tag topic.image.url, class: "topic-show" if topic.image? %>
    </div>

    <% if current_user && current_user.admin? %>
      <%= link_to "Edit", edit_topic_path(topic), :class => 'btn btn-default' %>
      <%= link_to "Destroy", topic, :class => 'btn btn-default', method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %>
    <% end %>
    <%= link_to "Show", topic_path(topic), :class => 'btn btn-default' %>
  <% end %>
<div>
<%= will_paginate @topic, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails %>
</end>
```

**topics_controller.rb, index action**

```
class TopicsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show, :index, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @topics = Topic.search(params[:search]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5
    @topics = Topic.all
  end
end
```

And I received an error

```
undefined method `'each'` for `nil:NilClass`
```

The error is thrown at `<% @topics.each do |topic| %>`.

[image: Error Shown Here]

I am unsure what to do. I have tried to add:

```rb
@topics = Topic.all
```

to `topics#index`, but that does not seem to resolve the issue.

Comment: Do you have topics in your database?

Comment: What action is called?

Comment: @hashrocket Yes I do have topics

Comment: @IgorKasyanchuk Please see updated question. By action, do you mean the error?

Comment: Show  full logs, from request started to crash

Comment: @IgorKasyanchuk Sorry I am quite new to Rails. How am I able to show you the full log?

Comment: Try removing `.search(params[:search])` from `@topics` in your index action and see if it works.

Comment: @hashrocket no luck! That didn't work.

Comment: The logs are in your console where you run your rails server. They can be useful. The image you posted is not useful. Also, images are bad because we can't copy and paste from the (if needed). And, they can be hard to see on some devices.

Comment: You have some typos in the question - are they present in your code too? Unclosed bracket in first @topics definition and incorrect `if-end` in html.erb (should be `<% if %>` and `<% end %>`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error just means that `@topics` is empty.

To troubleshoot this, you need to refresh the page while watching your console.

Examine the queries being ran when these lines run:

```
@topics = Topic.search(params[:search]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5
@topics = Topic.all
```

If you can't spot the issue in the console, copy the query into your database GUI and run the query, modify it till you get your expected results and edit the query.

I would assume that your issue might have to do with the params being passed.

You should add this before your queries to view what params you are picking up.

```
p 'my params'
p params[:search]
p params[:page]
```

PS. I suggest making your per_page a variable, it makes it easier when going through code to see all the hard coded values and change them when they are not in the middle of a code block.